# How should I invoke shell_exec or exec in php if I want all the commands to be run on same shell instance and not on different instances everytime?

Tags: php, apache, shell, exec, shell-exec

I am searching on one topic for nearly a week now and still cannot find a proper answer on the Internet. What i want to do is make multiple shell_exec or exec commands via my server which is running native PHP and I will be using shell_exec or exec function for that. But my problem is that everytime I invoke the function it creates a new shell instance and runs. But I want all my commands to be run in same shell instance. Any help on that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Open a new screen session. Name it `test`:

   `screen -S test`
2. Detach from the screen session with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> followed by a <kbd>d</kbd>.
3. Send the command to that screen session:

   `` screen -S test -X stuff 'echo enter command here'`echo -ne '\015'` ``
4. Wrap the above command in exec and set up the appropriate permissions (i.e., PHP should be able to access the `test` screen session).

Comment: Sorry but am new to PHP, can you be more specific. I did all the above in terminal but I got nothing relevant

Comment: If you run `screen -S test`, a screen session named `test` will be opened and a shell will launch there. The screen session runs even if you log out from the server. The third command sends commands to that shell, instead of launching and closing a shell each time you use shell_exec().